# Conditional insert of new records into transaction table

Tags: postgresql, join, transactional

I have a standing table of historical transactions and I would like to insert records from a new table where the status of the new record is different from the old at the time that the new record was "valid" (based on a `valid_from` column in both tables).

For example, take the standing/transactional table (I'll call it `old`):

```
CREATE TABLE old (id serial, key text, valid_from date, status text);
INSERT INTO old (key, valid_from, status)
VALUES
('A', '2014-01-01', 'x'),
('A', '2014-02-01', 'y'),
('A', '2014-03-01', 'z'),
('B', '2014-01-10', 'x'),
('B', '2014-02-15', 'y');

SELECT * FROM old;

 id | key | valid_from | status
----+-----+------------+--------
  1 | A   | 2014-01-01 | x
  2 | A   | 2014-02-01 | y
  3 | A   | 2014-03-01 | z
  4 | B   | 2014-01-10 | x
  5 | B   | 2014-02-15 | y
```

And the `new` table of updates:

```
CREATE TABLE new (id serial, key text, valid_from date, status text);
INSERT INTO new (key, valid_from, status)
VALUES
('A', '2014-01-15', 'x'),
('A', '2014-02-15', 'x'),
('A', '2014-03-15', 'z'),
('B', '2014-02-15', 'y');

SELECT * FROM new;

 id | key | valid_from | status
----+-----+------------+--------
  1 | A   | 2014-01-15 | x
  2 | A   | 2014-02-15 | x
  3 | A   | 2014-03-15 | z
  4 | B   | 2014-02-15 | y
```

Ideally, I would like to insert *only* row 2 of the new table because it has a different status than record with the same `key` in the `old` table with the most recent `valid_from` date prior to the new record. Specifically:

- `id` = 1 in the new table should not be inserted. The maximum `valid_from` date in the `old` table for key `A` ('2014-01-01') prior to the new `valid_from` date ('2014-01-15'); i.e., they both have a status of `x`.
- `id` = 2 in the new table *should* be inserted because its `status` (`x`) is different than the `status` in the `old` table (`y`) where the `valid_from` date in the old table was equal to the maximum `valid_from` for that key that is prior to the `valid_from` in the new table.
- `id` = 3 should not be inserted because it shares the same status (`x`) as the record in the old table for the most recent `valid_from`
- `id` = 4 should not be inserted because, again, it's status (`y`) is identical to the corresponding record in the `old` table.

After the insert, the `old` table should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM old ORDER BY key, valid_from;

 id | key | valid_from | status
----+-----+------------+--------
  1 | A   | 2014-01-01 | x
  2 | A   | 2014-02-01 | y
  6 | A   | 2014-02-15 | x
  3 | A   | 2014-03-01 | z
  4 | B   | 2014-01-10 | x
  5 | B   | 2014-02-15 | y
```

The goal: **there should never be two successive records with the same `key` and `status` when sorted by ascending `valid_from`.**

If the idea were to simply insert records with a `key` + `status` combination that did not exist in the `old` table, I would do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO old (key, valid_from, status)
SELECT new.key, new.valid_from, new.status
FROM new LEFT JOIN old USING(key, status)
WHERE old.key IS NULL;
```

However, this misses `id` 2 in the new table since `id` 1 in the old table shares the same status, even though there is a more recent record in the `old` table that does indeed differ.

Whatever I try, I can't seem to check the `new` record against *only* the most "recent" `old` record with a `valid_from` < the `valid_from` in the new record. I have a feeling I can do it with a combination of a window function and/or a DISTINCT ON to find the maximum valid_from, but I can't quite seem to put the two together. For instance, I've tried things like:

```
INSERT INTO old(key, valid_from, status)
SELECT n.key, n.valid_from, n.status
FROM new n LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (old.key) old.*
    FROM new
        JOIN old
        ON old.key = new.key
        AND old.valid_from < new.valid_from
        ORDER BY old.key, old.valid_from DESC) o
ON
    n.key = o.key
    AND n.status = o.status
WHERE
    o.key IS NULL;
```

However, this winds up inserting the first record from the `new` table:

```
 id | key | valid_from | status
----+-----+------------+--------
  1 | A   | 2014-01-01 | x
  6 | A   | 2014-01-15 | x
  2 | A   | 2014-02-01 | y
  7 | A   | 2014-02-15 | x
  3 | A   | 2014-03-01 | z
  4 | B   | 2014-01-10 | x
  8 | B   | 2014-02-15 | y
  5 | B   | 2014-02-15 | y
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3. Any pointers on an approach to this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more toying, I think I have a solution (although probably not the best one). The logical sequence of steps would be:

1. Join on the key, only where the new record's `valid_from` is greater than the old record's `valid_from`
2. For each match, include a flag for whether the old record's `valid_from` is the most recent `valid_from` among all candidate matches (we'll call it `is_most_recent`). I did this with a window function (which can't be used in a WHERE clause).
3. Ensure the new `status` does not equal the old `status`
4. Insert these records

Here's the best I've come up with so far:

```
INSERT INTO old (key, valid_from, status)
SELECT key, valid_from, status FROM (
    SELECT
        new.key, 
        new.valid_from, 
        new.status,
        -- Does the new record have a different statusf from the old?
        old.status != new.status AS is_different_status, 
        -- Are we comparing the most "recent" record in the old table?
        old.valid_from = MAX(old.valid_from) OVER (PARTITION BY old.key, new.id)
            AS is_most_recent
    FROM new JOIN old
        ON new.key = old.key
        AND new.valid_from >= old.valid_from) AS to_insert
WHERE is_different_status AND is_most_recent;
```

I'd love to know if there's a better solution out there.